# Why a free function passed as a parameter in the constructor is not called?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, constructor

Why doesn't the `mystruct( plain_old_function );` constructor calls the default constructor while the same with lambda calls the specialized one (`mystruct ( const std::function< std::string() > &func )`)?

Can this be made to work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct mystruct
{
    mystruct() { std::cout << "Default construct :S" << std::endl; }
    mystruct ( const std::function< std::string() > &func )  {
        std::cout << func() << std::endl;
    }
};

void callme ( const std::function< std::string() > &func )
{
    std::cout << func() << std::endl;
}

std::string free_function(  ) {  return "* Free function"; }


int main()
{

    std::cout << "Constructing with lambda:" << std::endl;
    mystruct( [](){ return "* Lambda function"; } );

    std::cout << "Calling free  function through another function:" << std::endl;
    callme( free_function );

    std::cout << "Constructing with free function:" << std::endl;
    mystruct( free_function );

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rqch9xLdAuaet0AM)

Output:

```
Constructing with lambda:
* Lambda function
Calling free  function through another function:
* Free function
Constructing with free function:
Default construct :S
```

Comment: Interesting.  If you change it to `mystruct foo( free_function );` then it does do the right thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vexing parse,

```
mystruct( free_function );
```

is parsed as

```
mystruct free_function; // declare a mystruct instance named free_function
                        // (hiding the function)
```

You may use `{}`:

```
mystruct{free_function};
```

Comment: **cross** The there is no way to do the following? ```mystruct( func ).aMemberFunc();```?

Comment: That way `mystruct{free_function}.aMemberFunc();`

Comment: Calling a member function doesn't work with the curly braces. Edit: My bad it does work.

Comment: @SteveRodeen [It works here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KgsKgF6xbj97OucY)

Answer (score 0):

While you should definitely prefer brace initialization, in this case you may avoid the vexing parse another way by doing qualified lookup instead of unqualified name lookup:

```
mystruct( ::free_function );
```

This cannot be resolved to introducing a new identifier named `free_function`.